# Dependency injection passing parameters to the Dependency

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

So I scoured through Stackoverflow with still no solution to my problem.

I'm trying to inject a dependency into a class, which is fairly simple to do through the constructor, However I want to pass some params to that Dependency. I tried to use service provider with no success. I'm sort of new to this concept so I'm definitely doing something wrong.

I have a class that needs a SoapClient dependency to work. How can I achieve that using the service provider and dependency injection.
Btw, I'm using Laravel.

This is what im doing now, instantiating the soap client inside the method:

```
namespace App\Services\;

Class Foo{

    public function __construct()
    {    
    }

    public  function getSomething($params)
    {
        $soapClient = new \SoapClient(env('wsdl'));
        $result = $soapClient->someMethod($params);
        return $result;
    }

}
```

This is sorta what I want to do:

```
namespace App\Services\;

Class Foo{

    public function __construct( \SoapClient $soap)
    {
        $this->soap = $soap
    }

    public  function getSomething($params)
    {
        $result = $this->soap->someMethod($params);
        return $result;
    }

}
```

But this of course that won't work because SoapClient class needs a wsdl parameter in order to instantiate.

Comment: It will work (process wise), because you'll instantiate `SoapClient` _before_ you instantiate `Foo`, then, when you instantiate `Foo` you'll pass in the instance of `SoapClient` which already has the wsdl param. Somebody else will need to explain how to do it with the service manager though.

Comment: Heh, I always thought these questions are just phishing attempts for certain developers, ie phishing how they have done it in their application. But what you are asking: `use YourSoapClient as whatever;` then typehint it in the function declaration. I don't understand the question btw. You have a working example

Comment: Or you can cheat and add factory/builder (mb add it to container) and init all dependencies there. This will waork until you fully understand dependency injection for Laravel and refactor this solution. Sorry I'm not experienced with Laravel

Comment: hey can you please answer the question the proper way with code.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following code to the `register` method in your `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider`:

```
$this->app->bind(\SoapClient::class, function ($app) {
    return new \SoapClient(env('wsdl'));
});
```

Alternatiely, you could run `php artisan make:provider SoapServiceProvider` to create a new serice provider, add the above code to the `register` method there, and add `Illuminate\View\SoapServiceProvider::class` to `providers` array in your `config/app.php` file.

Comment: i have already done that, but how do I call the dependency in the base class, If I typehint SoapClient in the constructor I get Unresolvable dependency and it tells me That SoapClient needs $wsdl parameter

Comment: You will need to resolve the `Foo` class out of the container as in: `resolve(App\Services\Foo::class)`. Only some classes in Laravel have "automatic injection" baked in.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by "out of the container"  and why Do I resolve Foo class, it's not even referenced inside of the service provider. where exactly do I put the resolve statement

Comment: In the place where you do `$foo = new Foo`, you should do `$foo = resolve(Foo::class)` instead. This way Laravel will be able to inject registered dependencies to `Foo`s constructor.

Comment: But in the code above you haven't referenced the Foo class anywhere, you just binded the SoapClient class to itself, how will resolving foo class inject the dependencies into it when the Foo class haven't been referenced anywhere inside the container

Comment: When you do `resolve(Foo::class)`, Laravel checks if there are any type-hinted arguments in `Foo`'s constructor, and automatically injects them. In your case this type-hinted argument is `SoapClient`. So `SoapClient` instance with `wsdl` argument value from `.env` will be injected into your `Foo` class. 

You don't always have to explicitely bind classes to the container to resolve them out of the container (a bit confusing) - it's mentioned in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/container#binding).

Comment: great thanks for clarifying, however After doing exactly what you said I'm getting this error right after resolving. 
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $wsdl ]] 
it looks like nothing is binding, and when I resolve nothing is passed to the Foo class,

Comment: Yes, it sounds like the code doing the binding wasn't executed. Can you double check if `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` is in the `providers` array in `config/app.php` (or if your custom provider is there, if you used one)?

Comment: I think I fixed it, I changed "$this->app->bind(\SoapClient::class, function (..."  
to "$this->app->bind(\MySoap::class, function (..." and then created the MySoap Class, and I type hinted the Soap in Foo class with MySoap, now everything works fine. do you think this is a sound approach?

Comment: How do you instantiate `SoapClient` now? Directly in `MySoap`'s constructor?

Comment: actually the MySoap class is empty, I'm just using it to tell the container when ever this class is called as a typehint, return SoapClient instant with the wsdl. not sure if this is the correct method but it works.

Comment: You may consider binding it to an interface instead (.e.g `SoapClientContract`). But generally yes, I think it's a good approach - especially that you got it to work :)

Comment: Sorry for bothering you but I want to achieve the best approach, where Do I make this interface class, and what should it consist of

Comment: It can be just an empty interface - you can put it directly in the `app` folder. There's nothing special about it - I only think binding an interface will make more sense than binding an empty class (I'm referring here to the solution you came up with - binding `MyClass` to the container).

Comment: actually I've tested my code now, its not working and the class I end up getting is not the SoapClient, it's the MySoap class which is empty so my plan doesn't work, I'm kinda lost right now. any ideas please?

Comment: Can you make sure the service provider is registered? Just put there `echo 'foo'; die;`, and see if it's shown on the screen when you access any route.